# Problems creating click chroot for 14.10

Tags: 15.04, 14.10, ubuntu-sdk, chroot, click-packages

I'm running 15.04 - trying to create a click chroot for 14.10 armhf:
works with 14.04, 15.04 but fails with 14.10.
Is 14.10 removed?

outpout as follows:

```
rp@rp-XPS:~$ click framework list
ubuntu-sdk-13.10
ubuntu-sdk-14.04-dev1
ubuntu-sdk-14.04-html-dev1
ubuntu-sdk-14.04-html
ubuntu-sdk-14.04-papi-dev1
ubuntu-sdk-14.04-papi
ubuntu-sdk-14.04-qml-dev1
ubuntu-sdk-14.04-qml
ubuntu-sdk-14.04
ubuntu-sdk-14.10-dev1
ubuntu-sdk-14.10-dev2
ubuntu-sdk-14.10-html-dev1
ubuntu-sdk-14.10-html-dev2
ubuntu-sdk-14.10-html
ubuntu-sdk-14.10-papi-dev1
ubuntu-sdk-14.10-papi-dev2
ubuntu-sdk-14.10-papi
ubuntu-sdk-14.10-qml-dev1
ubuntu-sdk-14.10-qml-dev2
ubuntu-sdk-14.10-qml-dev3
ubuntu-sdk-14.10-qml
ubuntu-sdk-14.10
ubuntu-sdk-15.04-html
ubuntu-sdk-15.04-papi
ubuntu-sdk-15.04-qml
ubuntu-sdk-15.04

rp@rp-XPS:~$ sudo click chroot -a armhf -f ubuntu-14.10 -s utopic -n foo create
I: Retrieving Release 
E: Failed getting release file http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/Release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 86, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 82, in main
    return mod.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/commands/chroot.py", line 266, in run
    return args.func(parser, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/commands/chroot.py", line 68, in create
    return chroot.create(args.keep_broken_chroot)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/chroot.py", line 527, in create
    self._debootstrap(components, mount, archive)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/chroot.py", line 451, in _debootstrap
    archive
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 561, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['debootstrap', '--arch', 'amd64', '--variant=buildd', '--components=main,restricted,universe,multiverse', 'utopic', '/var/lib/schroot/chroots/foo-ubuntu-14.10-armhf', 'http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

14.10 is End of Life and is no longer supported.  As a result, it is no longer on the archive mirrors, and is not available for the `sudo click chroot` option to create the chroot from.

Therefore, you can't create a chroot because the release no longer exists at the repository archive the system is trying to pull from.

Comment: looks like occams razor is to be applied here...

Comment: @renepaulokat Yep, occam's razor applies :)