# Problem installing Ubuntu 14.10 click package

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, click-packages

whenever I try to install Ubuntu 14.10 armfh click package,prompted with error below.

[[image: Here is Image[1]]

Answer (score 3):

First try to unregister

```
sudo click unregister --user=phablet click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf
```

if it still shows error then you can remove manually.

```
rm -rf /etc/schroot/chroot.d/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf
rm -rf /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf
```

then you can create again

```
sudo click chroot -a armhf -f ubuntu-sdk-14.10 create
```

Comment: thanks bro,your ans will work for any click problem other than 14.10 armfh because...ans is given in the link..anyways thanks. http://askubuntu.com/a/684691/500454